# Configuracion spf y dkim dominio externo

Tags: servidor, email, dns

trataré de ser breve para contextualizar.
Tengo un servidor en DigitalOcean con muchos proyectos. Uno de esos proyectos es: *ejemplo.com*. Para ejemplo.com contraté un *servidor de correo, 1&1ionos.com*. En el panel de ionos ya configuré el dominio externo (ejemplo.com) y los registros mx ya los anexé a DigitalOcean, está funcionando ok, puedo enviar y recibir correos desde @ejemplo.com.

Al enviar correos a un gmail, estos entran a las bandeja de entrada pero con un signo de interrogación rojo. Estuve averiguando y todo apunta a que me falta un registro spf. Aquí está la pregunta: Ese registro spf debo agregarlo en el apartado dns de DigitalOcean o del servidor de correo 1&1ionos.com?

Agradecería mucho sus comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: En teoría habria que setear los records dns TXT SPF y DKIM en la configuración DNS, en base a las claves que te entregue tu proveedor de email. Es decir, deberás obtener las claves desde el servidor de correo y configurarlas en el DNS de DigitalOcean.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Efectivamente, en mi caso, el spf es proporcionado por el servidor de correo (1&1 ionos), donde también tengo aparcado el dominio (dominio externo). Luego, este registro lo apliqué en mi droplet de Digital Ocean. Nuevamente, muchas gracias, fue muy útil.

Comment: también me sirvió añadir un registro FPS para mi dominio en IONOS para resolver el mismo problema con el correo.